# PHP/MYSQL datetime ranges overlapping for users

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

please I need help with this (for better understanding please see attached image) because I am completely helpless.

[image: http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/7196/overlapsen.jpg]

As you can see I have users and they store their starting and ending datetimes in my DB as YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s. Now I need to find out overlaps for all users according to the most frequent time range overlaps (for most users). I would like to get 3 most frequented datatime overlaps for most users. How can I do it?

I have no idea which mysql query should I use or maybe it would be better to select all datetimes (start and end) from database and process it in php (but how?). As stated on image results should be for example time 8.30 - 10.00 is result for users A+B+C+D.

```
Table structure:
UserID | Start datetime | End datetime
--------------------------------------
A | 2012-04-03 4:00:00 | 2012-04-03 10:00:00
A | 2012-04-03 16:00:00 | 2012-04-03 20:00:00
B | 2012-04-03 8:30:00 | 2012-04-03 14:00:00
B | 2012-04-06 21:30:00 | 2012-04-06 23:00:00
C | 2012-04-03 12:00:00 | 2012-04-03 13:00:00
D | 2012-04-01 01:00:01 | 2012-04-05 12:00:59
E | 2012-04-03 8:30:00 | 2012-04-03 11:00:00
E | 2012-04-03 21:00:00 | 2012-04-03 23:00:00
```

Comment: Please post the table structure. Do you want to run this for the current day/week/month/year/alltime?

Comment: from my point of view it is not important if it is current day/week/etc. because for example user D can have start datetime 2012-04-01 01:00:01 and end datetime 2012-04-05 12:00:59, and user A start datetime 2012-04-03 4:00:00 and end datetime 2012-04-03 10:00:00, user B start 2012-04-03 8:30:00 and end 2012-04-03 14:00:00 but my script should detect range overlapping for these users as start 2012-04-03 8:30:00 and end 2012-04-03 10:00:00 for users A+B+D.

Comment: The example below works based on creating timeslots for the current day. It should be enough to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: What if they overlap by only one second? Or by only 3 microseconds (on a different dbms that supports higher resolution timestamps)?

Comment: I have yet to come across people who manage their appointments to microsecond precision ;) Although with my proposed solution you do have the issue with bookings starting and finishing on the time_slot. It was only intended as a crude example to get the OP thinking about how he might solve his problem.

Comment: Sorry, @nnichols, I was aiming that question at the OP, not at you.

Comment: In the example above, why is 10:00-11:00 (B+D+E) not part of the expected resultset?

Answer (score 2):

What you effectively have is a collection of sets and want to determine if any of them have non-zero intersections. This is the exact question one asks when trying to find all the ancestors of a node in a nested set.

We can prove that for every overlap, at least one time window will have a start time that falls within all other overlapping time windows. Using this tidbit, we don't need to actually construct artificial timeslots in the day. Simply take a start time and see if it intersects any of the other time windows and then just count up the number of intersections.

So what's the query?

```
/*SELECT*/
SELECT DISTINCT
    MAX(overlapping_windows.start_time) AS overlap_start_time,
    MIN(overlapping_windows.end_time) AS overlap_end_time ,
    (COUNT(overlapping_windows.id) - 1) AS num_overlaps
FROM user_times AS windows
INNER JOIN user_times AS overlapping_windows
ON windows.start_time BETWEEN overlapping_windows.start_time AND overlapping_windows.end_time
GROUP BY windows.id
ORDER BY num_overlaps DESC;
```

Depending on your table size and how often you plan on running this query, it might be worthwhile to drop a spatial index on it (see below).

### UPDATE

If your running this query often, you'll need to use a spatial index. Because of range based traversal (ie. does start_time fall in between the range of start/end), a BTREE index will not do anything for you. IT HAS TO BE SPATIAL.

```
ALTER TABLE user_times ADD COLUMN time_windows GEOMETRY NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
UPDATE user_times SET time_windows = GeomFromText(CONCAT('LineString( -1 ', start_time, ', 1 ', end_time, ')'));
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX time_window ON user_times (time_window);
```

Then you can update the ON clause in the above query to read

```
ON MBRWithin( Point(0,windows.start_time), overlapping_windows.time_window )
```

This will get you an indexed traversal for the query. Again only do this if your planning on running the query often.

Credit for the spatial index to [Quassoni's blog](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/).

Comment: I thought this was an interesting answer so I tried it with SQL Fiddle, but it doesn't quite produce the expected results – http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2aad9/1/0 – maybe it can with a little tweaking.

Comment: That's a cool little tool! Just make it a SELECT DISTINCT to get rid of the duplicates (original post updated). Also the total count is 0 indexed, but you can just remove the minus 1 from the COUNT statement and add a HAVING num_overlaps > 1 if you want natural numbering. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2aad9/9

Comment: If your intereseted in how many time windows overlap, use overlapping_windows.id in the COUNT. If you want the number of users that overlap, just change it to overlapping_windows.user_id (see the fiddle). I also added another column to make it look exactly like your result set :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2aad9/16

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started -

```
SELECT slots.time_slot, COUNT(*) AS num_users, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_bookings.user_id ORDER BY user_bookings.user_id) AS user_list
FROM (
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL ((id-1)*30) MINUTE AS time_slot
    FROM dummy
    WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 48
) AS slots
LEFT JOIN user_bookings
    ON slots.time_slot BETWEEN `user_bookings`.`start` AND `user_bookings`.`end`
GROUP BY slots.time_slot
ORDER BY num_users DESC
```

The idea is to create a derived table that consists of time slots for the day. In this example I have used dummy (which can be any table with an AI id that is contiguous for the required set) to create a list of timeslots by adding 30mins incrementally. The result of this is then joined to bookings to be able to count the number of books for each time slot.

**UPDATE** For entire date/time range you could use a query like this to get the other data required -

```
SELECT MIN(`start`) AS `min_start`, MAX(`end`) AS `max_end`, DATEDIFF(MAX(`end`), MIN(`start`)) + 1 AS `num_days`
FROM user_bookings
```

These values can then be substituted into the original query or the two can be combined -

```
SELECT slots.time_slot, COUNT(*) AS num_users, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_bookings.user_id ORDER BY user_bookings.user_id) AS user_list
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(tmp.min_start) + INTERVAL ((id-1)*30) MINUTE AS time_slot
    FROM dummy
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(`start`) AS `min_start`, MAX(`end`) AS `max_end`, DATEDIFF(MAX(`end`), MIN(`start`)) + 1 AS `num_days`
        FROM user_bookings
    ) AS tmp
    WHERE dummy.id BETWEEN 1 AND (48 * tmp.num_days)
) AS slots
LEFT JOIN user_bookings
    ON slots.time_slot BETWEEN `user_bookings`.`start` AND `user_bookings`.`end`
GROUP BY slots.time_slot
ORDER BY num_users DESC
```

**EDIT** I have added `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` clauses in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` in response to your last query.

Please note that you will will need a much greater range of ids in the dummy table. I have not tested this query so it may have syntax errors.

Comment: so my default table is user_bookings with user_id, start, end. then I created table dummy with id (AI). but please what else should I do with table dummy? I am trying to make it work.

Comment: You do not need to create the table `dummy` although I do have one on my server to protect against holes left in an id sequence. You can use any table that has an id covering the required range. I have based this example on 48 * 30min slots covering the current day so you only need ids from 1 - 48.

Comment: thanks. it covers 48*30 but for today only. I think it is good for start but no idea how to accommodate it for my needs.

Comment: In that case you will have to better explain your needs. I did start by asking - "Do you want to run this for the current day/week/month/year/alltime?" You can increase the range used for creating the time slots to anything you want as long as you have large enough range of ids to pass in.

Comment: yes, I would like to run it for "alltime" or better to sayi can find out from db max and min value from start and date so I would like to run it in this datetime range.

Comment: This differs significantly from the OP's desired result: "time 8.30 - 10.00 is result for users A+B+C+D". Your top 3 would be the three half-hour slots between 8:30 and 10:00. The OP's top 3 would appear to be 8:30 to 10:00, 12:00 to 13:00, and one or more of several intervals that have 2 users.  That's an observation, not a criticism.

Comment: @Catcall - fair comment. I cannot figure out a computationally simple way of providing exactly the OP's desired result. peter - in that case you need to calculate the number of time slots required to cover your entire date/time range and use your minimum start value instead of CURRENT_DATE in the inner query.

Comment: @nnichols thank you! it looks nice and very useful. I found out that it generates for users 2,4,5 time slots 10:30 - 11:00 (but it should be 8:30 - 11:00), don't know why(?). other time slots seems to be ok. And for some times it generates in user_list '4,4' (I can clean it with php). maybe one more question: is there any ordering method for this (?) -when the same count of users are in user_list for two different datetimes I would like to prefer that datetime range which has longer time,e.g.if user_list '9,8' has common range 8:00-12:00 it should be on top before users '4,5' 8:0-10:0. thanks!

Comment: @peter - The problem with my solution is that it is based on creating a list of datetime values and then joining to the bookings. The resolution of the datetime values could be increased to minutes or even seconds but this would result in much larger and slower temp tables. This creates a few different problems. Firstly, assuming a value of '2012-01-01 10:30:00' it will join to a booking that finishes at that time and another booking that starts at that time although they do not really overlap. How many records do you have in this table and how large do you anticipate it will grow?

Answer (score 0):

I would not do much in SQL, this is so much simpler in a programming language, SQL is not made for something like this.

Of course, it's just sensible to break the day down into "timeslots" - this is statistics. But as soon as you start handling dates over the 00:00 border, things start to get icky when you use joins and inner selects. Especially with MySQL which does not quite like inner selects.

Here's a possible SQL query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `times`
WHERE
  ( DATEDIFF(`Start`,`End`) = 0 AND
    TIME(`Start`) < TIME('$SLOT_HIGH') AND
    TIME(`End`) > TIME('$SLOT_LOW'))
  OR
  ( DATEDIFF(`Start`,`End`) > 0 AND
    TIME(`Start`) < TIME('$SLOT_HIGH') OR
    TIME(`End`) > TIME('$SLOT_LOW')
```

Here's some pseudo code

```
granularity = 30*60; // 30 minutes
numslots = 24*60*60 / granularity;
stats = CreateArray(numslots);
for i=0, i < numslots, i++ do
  stats[i] = GetCountFromSQL(i*granularity, (i+1)*granularity); // low, high
end
```

Yes, that makes `numslots` queries, but no joins no nothing, hence it should be quite fast. Also you can easily change the resolution.

And another positive thing is, you could "ask yourself", "I have two possible timeslots, and I need the one where more people are here, which one should I use?" and just run the query twice with respective ranges and you are not stuck with predefined time slots.

To only find full overlaps (an entry only counts if it covers the full slot) you have to switch low and high ranges in the query.

You might have noticed that I do not add times between entries that could span multiple days, however, adding a whole day, will just increase all slots by one, making that quite useless.
You could however add them by selecting `sum(DAY(End) - DAY(Start))` and just add the return value to all slots.

Answer (score 0):

Table seems pretty simple.  I would keep your SQL query pretty simple:

SELECT * FROM tablename

Then when you have the info saved in your PHP object.  Do the processing with PHP using loops and comparisons.

In simplest form:

```
for($x, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++){

     /*Grab a row*/
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

     /*store userID, START, END*/
     $userID = $row['userID'];
     $start = $row['START'];
     $end = $row['END'];

     /*Have an array for each user in which you store start and end times*/  

     if(!strcmp($userID, "A")
     {
        /*Store info in array_a*/
     }
     else if(!strcmp($userID, "B")
     {
        /*etc......*/
     } 
}
 /*Now you have an array for each user with their start/stop times*/

 /*Do your loops and comparisons to find common time slots. */

 /*Also, use strtotime() to switch date/time entries into comparable values*/
```

Of course this is in very basic form. You'll probably want to do one loop through the array to first get all of the userIDs before you compare them in the loop shown above.